# Android development toolkits

Tags: android

Was wondering if anyone knew of some third party android development toolkits.

I have found Basic4Android.

Was wondering what other options are available.Language does not matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt for [Android](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/) (Alpha version) got launched last week.

Motorola has a custom dev environment built on top of eclipse ([MOTODEV](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/)). It is not Motorola specific and you can use it for regular development. I have been playing around with it for a week and it is much more convenient than the standard Android Eclipse plugin.

EDIT: Forgot to mention there is [AppInventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/) (currently in Beta) which is a drag and drop development environment from Google. It is a useful tool if you want to get a feel for development or you are developing just for your phone. It does not generate Java code (as yet) and there some restrictions on it like only single screen apps are supported. It has got a healthy community and lot of college students (in the U.S) seem to be using it.

Comment: **+1** It's nice and if you include some reference links then it would be really nice.

Answer (score 1):

[MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/) is also another development stack for Android using C# and .NET API's. You can use `Microsoft Visual Studio IDE` to develop applications using `MonoDroid`.